# Basic Multiplication Calculator Error in Python

Tags: python

I want to get the amount of a product from a string and multiply it by the product quantity, so I did

```
>>>trip='Standard Price:2000'
>>>price = trip.split(":")[1]

'2000'
```

I do the maths here

```
>>>price*2
```

But the answer I should get is `'4000'` not the one below:

```
>>>20002000
```

Isn't `*` symbol a multiplication sign? because when I checked that's the symbol don't know why I'm getting the raise to power answer. What did I miss?

Comment: By the way, 2000^2 == 4000000...not 20002000

Comment: `print(type(price))`. `type()` is the best when you find variables behaving oddly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert to [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) first:

```
int(price) * 2  # result: 4000
```

Then you can use mathematical operators as you know them. Otherwise you are multiplying strings:

```
"x" * 10  # result: "xxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to convert to `int` before multiplication:

```
>>> int(price)*2
```

if you multiply string with a number it will produce string that number of times:

Demo:

```
>>> 'a'*4
'aaaa'
```

Comment: You rock Hacka, always at my help when I'm in need. :)